# Get doublequotes with empty space between with perl and Text::CSV

Tags: perl, csv

I am using Text::CSV to build csv files. I need to get a line like

```
10;"";LS;1000
```

My problem are the double quotes with no space between. My best guess is

```
require Text::CSV::Encoded;
my $or_csv = Text::CSV::Encoded->new({
    sep_char    => ';',
    eol         => "\r\n",
    quote_char  => '"',
    quote_null  => 1,
    binary      => 1,
});

my @a_columns = (10, , 'LS', 1000);
$or_csv->combine(@a_columns);
print $or_csv->string;
```

but the result is

```
10;LS;1000
```

The only way I found to solve this is to disable quoting. But that's not what I want for security reasons.

Any help is very welcome.

Comment: Passing the list `10, , 'LS', 1000` does not do what you think, the "empty" field is simply ignored before the subroutine ever gets the arguments. If you want an empty argument, use `""`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but giving an empty string inside results in an empty field, not a field with doublequotes only.

Comment: The point would be that giving an empty string gives a result, whereas not giving anything but two commas in a row `,,` does not do anything at all and is completely ignored in your code. E.g. `1,,2,3` is equivalent to `1,2,3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [TLP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725418/tlp) commented, one issue is that your `@a_columns` initialization isn't creating the array you think it is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;

my @a_columns = ( 10,, 'LS', 1000 );
print Dumper \@a_columns;

my @b_columns = ( 10, '"', 'LS', 1000 );
print "\n", Dumper \@b_columns;

my $or_csv = Text::CSV->new(
    {
        sep_char   => ';',
        eol        => "\r\n",
        quote_char => '',
        binary     => 1,
        quote_null => 1
    }
);

$or_csv->combine(@b_columns);
print "\n", $or_csv->string;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          10,
          'LS',
          1000
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          10,
          '"',
          'LS',
          1000
        ];

10;"";LS;1000
```

Note that the `'"'` in the second list produces your desired array results, provided `quote_char => ''`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
my @a_columns = (10, '', 'LS', 1000);
```

Modified after [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) comment.

Comment: I tried this variant before and get 10;;LS;1000. I guess we are getting closer here.

Comment: @user2365175 The [CSV spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) only requires double quotes around fields containing commas, line breaks, and double quotes. Text::CSV extends things a bit by allowing any single-byte delimiter, but `10;;LS;1000` is perfectly valid; there's no need to quote empty fields. You can use the `always_quote` option to `Text::CSV->new` to quote *all* fields, but that's generally not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the very thing you do not want is that your 2nd column would be two double quotes. **Unless** you do intend to make other application see it as an empty string. However, your example showed something that looked like *ten, nothing, LS, thousand*.

So first of all, the input to `$csv->combine` is *LIST* as with all functions and methods. Multiple comma's **do not** mean that there are *undefined* elements in the list. Hence you ended up with only three columns.

Either:
Pass an empty string like `""`
or
pass `undef`

Just set `always_quote => 1`. Then when reading back in and parsing the CSV into Perl, the option `blank_is_undef => 1` is the thing that now will let you know if it was an empty string or if it was undefined.

BUT.... If you really must and insist:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

my $double_quotes_here = '<=- -=>'; # some fancy string WITH a space-character

$csv->combine(10, $double_quotes_here, 'LS', 1000);

my $csv_string = $csv->string;
$csv_string =~ s/$double_quotes_here//g;
print $csv_string, "\n";
```

Good luck!